# How does RememberMe setting work with WebSecurity in an MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies

In a sample/default MVC 4 project, I can see that when the User logs in with `Remember Me` checkbox on, the persistCookie parameter of the WebSecurity.Login method is set to true.

How exactly does that work?  Where exactly is the value of persistCookie is saved?  I looked through the tables that are created for the Security feature and do not see anywhere that the user is set to persist login.

What mechanism enables the user to log in? Is it simply the presence of the .ASPXAUTH cookie? Or does it actually compare the cookie value to something that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How exactly does that work?

By creating a [`persistent cookie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Persistent_cookie).

> Where exactly is the value of persistCookie is saved?

As a file on the client machine so that it survives browser restarts.

> What mechanism enables the user to log in?

This mechanism is called `persistent cookie`. A cookie is considered *persistent* if when being set the `Expires` property is being set to some date in the future. In this case the browser will store the cookie on the client computer as a file instead of keeping it in memory.

Here's an example of how creating a persistent cookie looks like in terms of the HTTP protocol:

```
Set-Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 12-Oct-2016 21:47:09 GMT;
```

And here's how a setting a session cookie looks like which will not survive browser restarts:

```
Set-Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue;Path=/;
```

Now go ahead, download [`Fiddler`](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and inspect the network traffic to see the difference.

Comment: I guess, I should have clarified.  How does it work from a standpoint of a server?  Is it simply the name of the User that is stored in the cookie?  And upon request, the system populates User.Identity.Name with it?

Comment: In both cases, it is the username that is encrypted and stored in the cookie value. Since the value is encrypted with the machine keys of the server, only the server can decrypt this value and read back the original username. If you attempt to modify the cookie value the server will detect that you are unable to encrypt this value with the proper keys because you don't know them. So basically you cannot impersonate yourself as a different user without knowing the machine keys. There's a special ASP.MET HttpModule that runs on each request and which decrypts the value of the cookie and if ...

Comment: ... successful it stores the username in the `User.Identity.Name` property so that you can have access to this value in your web methods.

Comment: One more question... If I bounce the server, does the cookie still work?  I am assuming that it should. Because all it does it set the User.Identity.Name value.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

The identity is stored in the cookie and decrypted upon each request.

Persistent cookie means that the cookie will be automatically attached to requests by the browser for some period of time.

No magic and also no need to store open sessions at the server side. As long as a cookie decrypts correctly, it is accepted as the server assumes that no one is able to forge a cookie on its own. This requires that the cookie value is encrypted or at least signed.

Comment: So is ALL that's stored in the cookie is the name of the User?  And if the cookie is properly decoded, ASP.NET stores the name in User.Identity.Name?  Is that how it works?

Comment: Pretty much. The cookie is de-crypted and used to create a new Principal and Identity, which is what fills in the User property and User.Identity. A good way to make sure that it can be decrypted is to set a machinekey specifically in your web.config. This will ensure that the same key is used whenever the application recycles. Google for machinekey generator and you should find some good options to choose from.